# Accessing Firebase Analytics data

Tags: swift, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

So I have an app which is already published on App Store and is supposed to show it's users some information and gather analytics data on which information is mostly viewed by users. App is using Firebase DB so I decided to use Firebase Analytics as well to gather that analytics data.

Whenever a user opens a category of articles, app sends and event called "category_opened" with a few parameters (including "category" parameter which contains category id). Everything looks to be working, I can see the events showing up in my Firebase Analytics Dashboard BUT theirs parameters are available only in the "Events in the last 30 minutes" of the dashboard. Whenever 30 minutes since the last event have passed, all the event's parameters disappear and I can't find a way to view them.

Is there any way to see the whole analytics information (all events for selected time period with all their parameters) or firebase is deleting the parameters data after 30 minutes and leaving only event's count?

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Events report in your app
- In the row for the event you want to modify, click More > Edit parameter reporting
- Enter the name of the parameter > Click ADD
- Set the Type field to Text or Number. For numeric parameters, set the Unit of Measurement field.
- Click SAVE, then click CONFIRM.

PS: You have a limit of 10 Text parameters & 50 Numeric parameters to be added per project.

[More Info](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7397304?hl=en)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I know about this option but I thought I was missing something out because 10 text parameters per project seems like not enough (at the moment I have 9 events and each of them has 3-5 text parameters). Well, looks like I'll have to look for alternative service for getting analytics data

Comment: Well, firebase currently supports `bigquery` alone to extract the raw data for reporting